# Twiitter python API failed to connect for streaming

Tags: api, twitter, vpn, tweepy

I am trying python twitter API for tweets streaming . My code after execution showing me this  . Any idea how can I remove it?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 160, in _new_conn
>       (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
>   line 80, in create_connection
>       raise err   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
>   line 70, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 603, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 344, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 843, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 316, in connect
>       conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 169, in _new_conn
>       self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e) urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
>   : Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 449, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 641, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
>   line 399, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused
>   by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\twitter\python
>   twitter_lucidprograming.py", line 57, in 
>       twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename, hash_tag_list)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\twitter\python
>   twitter_lucidprograming.py", line 24, in stream_tweets
>       stream.filter(track=hash_tag_list)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py",
>   line 474, in filter
>       self._start(is_async)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py",
>   line 389, in _start
>       self._run()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py",
>   line 320, in _run
>       six.reraise(*exc_info)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\six.py",
>   line 693, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py",
>   line 273, in _run
>       proxies = self.proxies)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 516, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stream.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length (Caused
>   by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

I am in China, Twitter is blocked accessing twitter through VPN. furthermore I want to know 
1- once when we get authentication keys it is important to be longed in on twitter and developer account or no need of it.

2- if VPN can be issue how I can resolve it?

3- Might be a chance I didnot install tweepy right, When I run command on cmd "pip install tweepy" it says requirement already satisfied. How I can check tweepy installed well?